# Launch a service after the intallation of my Android application

Tags: android

Do you know if it is possible to launch a service directly after the installation of my application on the phone ?

Thanks

Comment: i'd say you have a pretty good chance the user will open the app shortly after downloading and installing. just start that service when the app first launches!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. But you can check if your application is first started.

Comment: use `SharedPreferences.Editor` and `SharedPreferences`.  set a boolean flag to `true` if the preference does not exist.  get the boolean pref, if `false` do your "first run" stuff.  maybe ask a new question if you can't go further!

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible or supported in Android.  You can do it the first time the App is opened.