# Android - How would you go about installing setup data from the internet

Tags: android

I am working on an android application that uses data from the internet. On first use, downloading and inserting data into the database takes a some time which might make the user feel that the application is non-responsive and might drive impatient users away immediatly. I am currently displaying a progress dialog to inform the user that this operation might take some time to complete (around 1/2 a minute).

is there a way to install all the data while installing the application, ie. before first use?

Comment: Why don't you download a DB and skip the insertion step?

Comment: @Matthew Read Because the data is updated daily so it would be outdated after a week

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do this. Other applications can capture `Intent` after an app is downloaded, but not if it is the app that was just downloaded.

This question is similar to [Launch a service after the intallation of my Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492255/launch-a-service-after-the-intallation-of-my-android-application).